# Transpose and split data adding N number of empty columns after each blank cell (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On google sheets I'm trying to split a column on every empty cell then transposing the column and adding N number of empty columns (in example N=2) after each split resulting from a blank cell. One difficulty I am having is the number of empty cells vary between each set on the data. Attached is sample of data and desired output

[image: initial data]

I tried using a combination of split and transpose but was unable to get desired output.

Desired

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the formula a little bit, just realized that my latter-added filter also helped for the first one.

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(
 IFERROR(
  SPLIT(
    TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
      LAMBDA(mapped,JOIN("╬",FILTER(mapped,mapped<>"")))
        (MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(ROW(x)=1,x,IF(AND(x="",OFFSET(x,-1,0)<>""),REPT("SPLIT",B1+1),x))))),
     "SPLIT",,))
    ,"╬",1,1)
  ,"")
))
```

I'll try to explain it from the inside to the outside:

`MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(ROW(x)=1,x,IF(AND(x="",OFFSET(x,-1,0)<>""),REPT("SPLIT",B1+1),x))))` goes all through the column, when it finds a cell that is blank and its previous one wasn't (that's why OFFSET with -1, it goes "up" one row) then it repeats the word "SPLIT" N times in that cell (you can try pasting only this part to see the effect)

Then i added a LAMBDA function in order not to repeat all this expression when trying to filter. `LAMBDA(mapped,JOIN("╬",FILTER(mapped,mapped<>"")))` I named "mapped" to the result of the previous operation, FILTER allows you to skip the empty rows (that would be the extra rows you have in A12 or A23:25). And then JOIN with that symbol ╬ (that you can change to another you like). Now you have a loooong string with ╬ between what used to be cells and SPLITSPLITSPLIT when you had the division of categories

TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(....,"SPLIT",,)). With SPLIT now you divide all that long string in one cell per column with each category that looks like this: Birds╬Double Crested╬Great Blue Heron╬ and with TRANSPOSE you make it into this:

[image]

Now you SPLIT again with the symbol: `SPLIT(.....,"╬",1,1))` Those last 1,1 let's you avoid empty spaces. And the previous `INDEX and IFERROR` goes all through the "chart" in the previous screenshot row by row

Finally,TRANSPOSE again let you recover the original position of rows and columns, now divided

I hope it is clearer now!

B1 is the place where you can set that "N" amount of columns in between your results. Basically it repeats the word "SPLIT"(it can be anyone you choose, or any symbol, obviously)
You can test it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xTuG06Fw0b7vnc2ez1cWICbTkm99DfXJi56SlkqJ1M/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly. Is there by any chance a simpler approach that is possible? My knowledge of google sheets is not as advanced to understand all functions used

Comment: I _tried_ to explain in the update of the post!

Comment: And yes, at least from my not that long experience, I think that every step is necessary given the conditions of your source date and desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(a="", "×", a&"​"),,9^9), "×"))), 
 "select Col1,'​','​​' where Col1 is not null label '​''','​​'''", ))), "​"))))
 (A1:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]